# Rest API return response incorrect XML format using C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to get a XML from a asmx using a post.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"https://.../esiat.asmx/RecepcionarNFSe");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = client.Send(request);
    var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And I'm not getting the corret XML, its coming with this response.

[image]

What I'm dong wrong?

Corrent data is :

```
    
<tcRetornoNFSe><tcValidaGrcNFSe><tsFlgEtt>V</tsFlgEtt><tsDesOco>Estrutura do Arquivo XML OK!</tsDesOco></tcValidaGrcNFSe><tcInfRetNFSe><tsNumNot>37436</tsNumNot><tsCodVer>VMR4NBUTTW</tsCodVer><tsFlgRet>V</tsFlgRet><tsDesOco>NFSe Importado com sucesso.</tsDesOco><tsLnk>https://nfe.araxa.mg.gov.br/Valida_NFELogo_Emissao.aspx?InscricaoMunicipal=3070326219&amp;Distrito=1&amp;NumeroNota=37436&amp;CodVrfNfe=VMR4NBUTTW</tsLnk></tcInfRetNFSe></tcRetornoNFSe>
```

Comment: `var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` is a string. You now have to load it into an XML document. The response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your response is HTML encoded and is located inside the  tag. You can extract the content of that tag then use the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-7.0)

```
var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var startTag = "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
var endTag = "</string>";
int startIndex = str.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
int endIndex = str.IndexOf(endTag);
string innerText = str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
string decodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(innerText);
```

This will make your string a "xml string", I tried to scape the string if it don't work please make the adjustments necessary to find the index.

Comment: When trying the HtmlDecoce, I got the XML but this XML is not the valid XML because the node <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

Comment: The XML content you want is inside the tag <string>, that tag is a placeholder from a C# ASMX service. Just extract the text inside that tag and Decode it, Ill update my answer. Btw next time provide Textual codes on your question xD.